# Deprecation warning for Objective-C dependencies

Tags: objective-c, swift, deprecation-warning

## Making Swift var backwards compatible with Objective-C

I have an Objective-C class I've converted to Swift. All my tests pass, but I'd like to further optimize it by adding a deprecation warning to update to notify users to update downstream dependencies to the Swift version of the var (`Decimal`) if they can. Whether they can depends upon whether the class they're using is an Objective-C class (which can only "see" `NSDecimalNumber`) or a Swift class. Is there a way to do this? This is what I've got so far.

```
  @available(swift, introduced: 5.0)
  public var mySwiftDecimal: Decimal?

  @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "mySwiftDecimal")
  public var myObjCDecimal: NSDecimalNumber? {
      get {
          return mySwiftDecimal as NSDecimalNumber?
      } set {
          mySwiftDecimal = newValue as Decimal?
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the member as deprecated in Swift:

```
@available(swift, deprecated: 5.0, renamed: "mySwiftDecimal")
@objc public var myObjCDecimal: NSDecimalNumber? {
    get {
        return mySwiftDecimal as NSDecimalNumber?
    } set {
        mySwiftDecimal = newValue as Decimal?
    }
}
```

Then using it from Swift gives a warning:

```
let foo = Foo()
print(foo.myObjCDecimal)
// 'myObjCDecimal' is deprecated: renamed to 'mySwiftDecimal'
```

but using it from Objective-C does not:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
NSDecimalNumber *dec = foo.myObjCDecimal;
```