# Restricting code to Objective-C or Swift callers

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm in the process of converting some legacy Objective-C and I've encountered a weird issue. The code in question is a protocol defined in Objective-C, but callers of the code are a mixed bag of Swift & Objective-C.

I'm curious if there's a way via deprecation warnings to restrict a caller to Swift-only or Objective-C-only. I'm thinking of keeping the Objective-C protocol around and adding the same protocol methods in a separate Swift protocol with the end goal of nuking the Obj-C when I'm done converting all the Obj-C to Swift.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59669955/1187415? I don't know if it works with protocols. – Oops, that is your question as well! So you probably already tried that.

Comment: LOL. Same neighborhood, different house. I'm gonna fiddle around and see if I can come up with something. I thought I'd throw a question up before I begin fiddling.

Comment: @MartinR Figured it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The protocol in question had error handling which is different between Objective-C and Swift. While I'm unable to post specific code, from a high level, I did the following:

### Starting Objective-C Protocol

```
@protocol MyObjCProtocol
```

### Objective-C Protocol (Update)

The Obj-C protocol declaration had a mixed bag of Objective-C & Swift objects conforming to it. This made for some compiler weirdness. What I ended up doing is generating headers within Xcode for Swift 5.0 and copying those to a NEW Swift-only protocol declaration.

```
NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("Conform to MySwiftProtocol for Swift classes")
@protocol MyObjCProtocol
```

### Swift Protocol (New)

```
@available(swift, introduced: 4.0)
public protocol MySwiftProtocol { // all the methods }
```